# ArcObjects 10.0: Adding Annotation Feature Class To Map

Tags: arcobjects, annotation

ArcObjects 10.0,
SDE on MS Sql Server,
Visual Studio 2010,
C#.Net

Using ArcObjects, I am able to add feature classes to the map with no problem.  However, when adding an annotation feature class to the map, the layer appears with the red exclamation point, which indicates that it is not valid.

Can someone provide some code that shows how to properly add an annotation feature class to a map?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the problem was not the ArcObjects, it was the underlying data.  At least in my case, there is no need to treat the annotation feature class as anything special compared to adding a regular vector feature class.

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you might want to [merge your accounts](http://gis.stackexchange.com/help/user-merge) as it appears you have created two.